# Why is there a decrease in the performance of pre-trained Deep Learning models?

Tags: binary, deep-learning, classification, keras, pre-trained-model

Doing binary classification with infected/uninfected RBCs (something the pretrained DL models have never seen before) using models and weights from Keras. I find the performance of the models (vgg16,19,xception) decrease with increase in the number of training and validation instances. Why?

Comment: Are you adding a new class to the final prediction? Output dimension increased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is related to resource management where you are doing inference and the model expands in the memory and it can decrease the performance. This situation will create a lot of Main memory access to perform the forward pass computations and page faults are occurring and it can decrease the performance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. The issue is that the I'm not using adequate number of epochs while fine-tuning the network to learn the new features. As I increase the number of epochs and do permutations with the SGD learning rate, I could find that the performance is increasing.